# Preg match does not work

Tags: preg-match

Hello can someone convert this ereg to preg_match without using any of its existing expressions? I mean the delimiters like / # etc..

```
if(!ereg("^(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))$", $local_array[$i])) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any char that is not in the expression will do it as delimiter so this:

```
if(!preg_match("¤(([A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-][A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~\.-]{0,63})|(\"[^(\\|\")]{0,62}\"))¤", $local_array[$i])) {
```

should work